# How to automatically apply wpa_supplicant configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, dhcp, wpa-supplicant

To authenticate in a corporate network I have to run the following command:

```
$ sudo wpa_supplicant -i eth0 -D wired -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/mywired.conf -B
```

The configuration script loaded thereby looks like this:

```properties
# global configuration
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
#ctrl_interface_group=wheel
ap_scan=0

# 802.1x wired configuration    

# eap-ttls
network={
    key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
    eap=TTLS
    identity="me@example.com"
    anonymous_identity="anonymous@example.com"
    password="password"
    ca_cert="/home/user/deutsche-telekom-root-ca-2.pem"
    phase2="auth=PAP"
    eapol_flags=0
    priority=5
}

# eap-peap
network={
    key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
    eap=PEAP
    identity="me@example.com"
    anonymous_identity="anonymous@htw-berlin.de"
    password="password"
    ca_cert="/home/user/deutsche-telekom-root-ca-2.pem"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    eapol_flags=0
    priority=10
}
```

Without the configuration I do **not** get an IP address assigned via DHCP.
How can I **automatically** apply this configuration at startup? I am running Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your command in /etc/rc.local. Make sure it's on a single line.

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -i eth0 -D wired -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/mywired.conf -B
```

I assume that your connection is stable and not dropping. Do comment if your connection drops. I'll make a script. Have to sleep now.

Comment: Can you explain why it works on another machine the way I described as [I mentioned before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182847/how-to-automatically-apply-wpa-supplicant-configuration#comment309495_185406)?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Maybe the rc.local's execute bit is disabled?

try this on the defective setup:

`sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

or

`sudo chmod 770 /etc/rc.local`

Comment: I managed to get it running as told in your initial answer. I did not have to change the file permissions. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want wpa-supplicant to run using that config upon boot, then you should put the command in *rc.local*.
As root, open up */etc/rc.local* in a text editor and paste in your command:

```
wpa_supplicant -i eth0 -D wired -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/mywired.conf -B
```

Make sure that *Systemd* is running *rc.local*:

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local
```

and reboot. Should work.

EDIT:

Failing that, you can also just write your own *systemd* rule.

First, save your wpa-supplicant  command to somewhere sensible, like */usr/local/bin* or */opt* and make it executable.
The file should look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
wpa_supplicant -i eth0 -D wired -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/mywired.conf -B
```

Let's assume you have called it *wpastart.sh*.
Now create a file in */usr/lib/systemd/system* and name it something like *wpa.service*.
Open the empty file in a text editor and make it look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=WPA Supplicant Startup

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/wpastart.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start the service as usual:

```
systemctl enable wpastart.service
```

And you have now written your first *systemd* startup script.

Comment: When I execute `sudo systemctl enable rc-local` the following is output: http://pastebin.com/psFJBcjj

Comment: I've edited my answer, adding instructions on writing your own startup script, since rc.local is not working for you.

Comment: I appreciate your tutorial and would try that. To mention on Ubuntu 14.10 there is no path like */usr/lib/systemd/system*, just */usr/lib/systemd*. - Apart from that I have a second machine which **automatically connects** to the network. It also has the configuration file but in */etc/mywired.conf* instead */etc/wpa_supplicant/mywired.conf*. I do not remember how I wired it up there.

Comment: If your distro starts wpa_supplicant using systemd in the first place, it might be easier to modify the existing unit file. There are often provisions for options in `/etc` which the unit file will load automatically, as well.

Comment: @TomHunt ... which means I should do what?

Comment: @KlaatuvonSchlacker Do you have an idea how I can find out why it works on the second computer?

Comment: It may be, as @TomHunt says, that your second computer starts wpa_supplicant (or a service that then uses wpa_supplicant itself). I am not sure why one computer would be different that the other by default, but maybe you set something up differently. Are you using NetworkManager or Wicd or any kind of graphical network configurator or are you determined to do this manually (it's ok if you are) ?